# Population vs Sampling Frame vs Sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, survey-sampling

Could someone please explain how the sampling frame is different from population and sample?

I understand that the population is all the sampling unit that match our criteria for the study. And the sample is those select few who participate in the study.

Now, the different answers I have gone through suggests that the sampling frame is from where you draw your sample. But don't we draw our sample from the population?

And if the sampling frame defines the criteria for sampling, then how that criteria is different from the criteria we laid down to define our population.

It will be a great help if you could please provide an example for stating all 3 i.e Population, Sampling frame and sample.

Hope I am clear with the question!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: think about the timing - is data collection instantaneous? or is there a lag between when you select the sample and when you ask the question?

Comment: Yes there is lag. I have defined a problem statement and identified my population. Say I want to study use of a medical device by cardiologists, now my population is all the cardiologists and I can do a sampling here and approach them. How will frame come in play to define my sample?

Comment: Also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207930/population-vs-sampling-frame-vs-sample.